# Call object that another object is contained in

Tags: php

So I'd like to be able to call a method of an object from a created object as deep as I'd like.

For example

```
$test = new sampleObject;
$test2 = $test->createChild();
$test3 = $test2->createChild();
...
```

catch is, I need to be able to refer to a method from the topmost creator class.

so I have my main class

```
class sampleObject
{
    public $tons, $of, $properties;

    public function createChild()
    {
        $someVar = new childObject();
        $this->otherMethod();
        return $someVar();
    }

    public function otherMethod()
    {
        //Do some stuff
    }
}

class childObject
{
    public $child, $properties;

    function createChild()
    {
        $someVar = new childObject();
        //here is my issue
        //I need to call a otherMethod from the creating class here but not static .
        return $someVar;
    }
}
```

Is this the wrong approach or is there a way to reference that creating class object.
I'd like to keep the created object's properties secluded from the creator class.

I thought about just passing the object, but I'd like to keep the same structure if possible as the creator class.

Comment: As spec'd your childObject does not "extend" anything and therefore has no parent object.

Comment: Right, that's my issue. The main class creates the sub class; but is there a more correct way to do this?

Comment: Check out the factory pattern. It seems like it might be what you want. I am having a hard time making sense the current code's purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I could find to do this was to pass the object that it is a part of to the sub-object.

so `$test2 = $test->createChild($test);`

and

```
class childObject
{
    public $child, $properties, $parent;

    function createChild()
    {
        $someVar = new childObject($parent);
        $this->parent = $parent;
        //here is my issue
        //I need to call a otherMethod from the creating class here but not static .
        return $someVar;
    }
}
```